# Receiving no data in streaming response/api call

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, stream, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to stream the response of a particular method in my controller but it gives me no data. Is there a better way to implement this?

The method is streamService.getLocationData();

Expected output -

```
{uncertaintyRadiusInMeters=[64], latitude=[12.345678], longitude=[-12.345678], dateTimeCaptured=[1623431888949]}
```

SpringBoot Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request-location", method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> requestLocation(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> form) {

    streamService.addDataToStream(form);
    streamService.buildShardIterator();
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> streamService.getLocationData();
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
            .body(responseBody);
```

//        return  streamService.getLocationData();
}

Service -

```
public ResponseEntity getLocationData() {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonKinesis kinesisClient = AmazonKinesisClient.builder()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();

    GetRecordsRequest recordsRequest = new GetRecordsRequest();
    recordsRequest.setShardIterator(shardIterator.getShardIterator());
    recordsRequest.setLimit(1000);

    GetRecordsResult recordsResult = kinesisClient.getRecords(recordsRequest);
    while (!recordsResult.getRecords().isEmpty()) {
        recordsResult.getRecords().stream()
                .map(record -> new String(record.getData().array()))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        recordsRequest.setShardIterator(recordsResult.getNextShardIterator());
        kinesisClient.getRecords(recordsRequest);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(recordsResult);
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to use `StreamingResponseBody` when you're not actually *streaming* the response as you're building it? The point of `StreamingResponseBody` is that it provides a callback method for you to implement, passing the `OutputStream` to that method, so the method can write directly to the output stream as the response is generated. Your lambda expression `outputStream -> streamService.getLocationData()` is not using the `outputStream` parameter, so yu get no response data. What were you trying to accomplish by using `StreamingResponseBody`?

Comment: @Andreas I'm trying to output to the browser (streaming) the output of my kinesis data stream. I'll then use that information to plot on a map. I've never streamed to the browser before, so I'm at a bit of a loss on the right way to do this.

Comment: @Andreas I tried this doing directly on the method itself and received nothing back then as well

Comment: You say you're trying to stream, but you're not *streaming*. The code is building up the entire response in POJOs in `recordsResult`, then mass-converting to JSON at the end. The point of streaming is to send the data as it is being collected, so you *don't* build up memory, and so you start sending sooner, thereby reducing the amount of space needed and improving the performance.

Comment: In order to actually stream, you need to send the `outputStream` parameter into the `getLocationData()` method, so it can render the next object into JSON and send it *inside* the `while` loop. This means that the code needs to invoke the JSON renderer itself, since if can no longer rely on the Spring framework to do it automatically. --- If you don't want to stream, don't use `StreamingResponseBody`, and refactor the code so you only create one `ResponseEntity`, not two, i.e. decide whether it is really the responsibility of `getLocationData()` to create one.

Comment: @Andreas I understand what you're saying now, but I'm having a problem implementing it (without getting rid of GetRecordsResult.) Is there documentation somewhere on this? I'm not able to find any/null out how to make this work in my case.

Comment: Since we don't know what `GetRecordsResult` is, we can't help with that. For streaming, you get an `OutputStream`, so your code is supposed to write bytes to the stream, the bytes being UTF-8 encoded JSON text. How you generate that JSON text is up to you, and is an entirely different question, and we can't help with that either, for the same reason, i.e. we don't know what `recordsResult` is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old V1 API for this service. Amazon very much recommends moving to V2:

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

The Kinesis V2 examples work. TO put a record into a data stream, use this Java code:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.PutRecordRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.KinesisException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.DescribeStreamRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.DescribeStreamResponse;
//snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.putrecord.import]

/**
 * To run this Java V2 code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class StockTradesWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    StockTradesWriter <streamName>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    streamName - The Amazon Kinesis data stream to which records are written (for example, StockTradeStream)\n\n" +
                "Example:\n" +
                "    StockTradesWriter streamName\n";

            if (args.length != 1) {
                System.out.println(USAGE);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            String streamName = args[0];
            Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
            KinesisClient kinesisClient = KinesisClient.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .build();

            // Ensure that the Kinesis Stream is valid
            validateStream(kinesisClient, streamName);
            setStockData( kinesisClient, streamName);
            kinesisClient.close();
    }

        // snippet-start:[kinesis.java2.putrecord.main]
        public static void setStockData( KinesisClient kinesisClient, String streamName) {

            try {
            // Repeatedly send stock trades with a 100 milliseconds wait in between
            StockTradeGenerator stockTradeGenerator = new StockTradeGenerator();

            // Put in 50 Records for this example
            int index = 50;
            for (int x=0; x<index; x++){
                StockTrade trade = stockTradeGenerator.getRandomTrade();
                sendStockTrade(trade, kinesisClient, streamName);
                Thread.sleep(100);
             }

        } catch (KinesisException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    private static void sendStockTrade(StockTrade trade, KinesisClient kinesisClient,
                                       String streamName) {
        byte[] bytes = trade.toJsonAsBytes();
        // The bytes could be null if there is an issue with the JSON serialization by the Jackson JSON library.
        if (bytes == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not get JSON bytes for stock trade");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Putting trade: " + trade.toString());
        PutRecordRequest request = PutRecordRequest.builder()
                .partitionKey(trade.getTickerSymbol()) // We use the ticker symbol as the partition key, explained in the Supplemental Information section below.
                .streamName(streamName)
                .data(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(bytes))
                .build();
        try {
            kinesisClient.putRecord(request);
        } catch (KinesisException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private static void validateStream(KinesisClient kinesisClient, String streamName) {
        try {
            DescribeStreamRequest describeStreamRequest = DescribeStreamRequest.builder()
                    .streamName(streamName)
                    .build();

            DescribeStreamResponse describeStreamResponse = kinesisClient.describeStream(describeStreamRequest);

            if(!describeStreamResponse.streamDescription().streamStatus().toString().equals("ACTIVE")) {
                System.err.println("Stream " + streamName + " is not active. Please wait a few moments and try again.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }catch (KinesisException e) {
            System.err.println("Error found while describing the stream " + streamName);
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.putrecord.main]
    }
}
```

TO retrieve data from a data stream, use this code:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.DescribeStreamResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.DescribeStreamRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.Shard;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.GetShardIteratorRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.GetShardIteratorResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.Record;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.GetRecordsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.GetRecordsResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.getrecord.import]

/**
 * Demonstrates how to read data from a Amazon Kinesis Data Stream. Before running this Java code example, populate a Data Stream
 * by running the StockTradesWriter example. That example populates a Data Stream that you can then use for this example.
 * Also, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetRecords <streamName>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    streamName - The Amazon Kinesis data stream to read from (for example, StockTradeStream).\n\n" +
                "Example:\n" +
                "    GetRecords streamName\n";

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String streamName = args[0];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        KinesisClient kinesisClient = KinesisClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getStockTrades(kinesisClient,streamName);
        kinesisClient.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[kinesis.java2.getrecord.main]
    public static void getStockTrades(KinesisClient kinesisClient, String streamName) {

            String shardIterator;
            String lastShardId = null;

            // Retrieve the Shards from a Stream
            DescribeStreamRequest describeStreamRequest = DescribeStreamRequest.builder()
                    .streamName(streamName)
                    .build();
            List<Shard> shards = new ArrayList<>();

            DescribeStreamResponse streamRes;
            do {
                streamRes = kinesisClient.describeStream(describeStreamRequest);
                shards.addAll(streamRes.streamDescription().shards());

                if (shards.size() > 0) {
                    lastShardId = shards.get(shards.size() - 1).shardId();
                }
            } while (streamRes.streamDescription().hasMoreShards());

            GetShardIteratorRequest itReq = GetShardIteratorRequest.builder()
                    .streamName(streamName)
                    .shardIteratorType("TRIM_HORIZON")
                    .shardId(shards.get(0).shardId())
                    .build();

            GetShardIteratorResponse shardIteratorResult = kinesisClient.getShardIterator(itReq);
            shardIterator = shardIteratorResult.shardIterator();

            // Continuously read data records from shard.
            List<Record> records;

            // Create new GetRecordsRequest with existing shardIterator.
            // Set maximum records to return to 1000.
            GetRecordsRequest recordsRequest = GetRecordsRequest.builder()
                     .shardIterator(shardIterator)
                     .limit(1000)
                     .build();

           GetRecordsResponse result = kinesisClient.getRecords(recordsRequest);

           // Put result into record list. Result may be empty.
           records = result.records();

            // Print records
            for (Record record : records) {
                SdkBytes byteBuffer = record.data();
                System.out.println(String.format("Seq No: %s - %s", record.sequenceNumber(),
                 new String(byteBuffer.asByteArray())));
             }
         }
        // snippet-end:[kinesis.java2.getrecord.main]
  }
```

You can find all V2 examples for Kinesis here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/kinesis/src/main/java/com/example/kinesis

If you have never worked with V2 API, then i recommend starting here:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't update that to v2 at the moment (ill be doing it in the near future.) Is there a way to stream the results of my while loop to the browser with my current setup?

I'm not getting anything with the code you see at the moment, but I'm definitely seeing it in my Intellij console.

Comment: I understand that some projects already use V1. I will look into Spring and V1.  There are plans to develop a Spring BOOT app using Kinesis Java API V2 that can stream data from a data stream and display the results in a view.  I will post back my findings on Spring and V1.

Comment: In case anyone is reading this and wondering where existing V2 and Spring Boot examples can be located - see: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for any help you can give me